# How can I maintain session after login using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm succeeded logging in sites using Selenium in Python 3.4
The login process is like below:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get('url')

emailElem = self.browser.find_element_by_name('user_id')
emailElem.send_keys(user_id)

passwordElem = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password') 
passwordElem.send_keys(user_pwd)

passwordElem.submit()
```

After I login, I'm trying to access certain page where the log-in session is required,

```
browser.get('login-session-required-page-url')
```

It lost its session and not allowed to access.

I think that this is related with session and cookies, but I have no idea how to deal with it.

Answer (score -1):

Is your `String` Object inside your `browser.get` parenthesis a functional url after you have successfully logged in regularly on a mainstream browser?

If you were to login manually instead of through selenium, the new URL that you want to access (the one which requires that the User is Logged In), should be the String URL inside your `browser.get`.

There are a few potential issues with your code. You did not specify any waiting time in between submitting through `submit()` and the next `browser.get()`.

Consider adding a 10 to 30 second wait in between like so :

```
passwordElem.submit()

browser.implicitly_wait(10)

browser.get('https://www.YourSite.com/LoggedIn/User/SomeNewPageThatRequiresBeingSignedIn/')
```

Another possibility is that the URL you are accessing after Logging in is unique to the cookies you were given only at the most recent logged in session. Try to see if the URL is exactly the same over multiple logins through different browsers at different times. It may be that you are issued a unique URL every time you Login.